# Android Chip_How to make chip background color transparent programmatically?

Tags: android, android-chips

I want to make the android chip background color to transparent.

From material version higher than 1.1.0,
we need to set `app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"` but also `app:chipSurfaceColor="@color/transparent"`

Ok, I see. But how can it do by kotlin code?

background color can be set by code below...

```kotlin
chipBackgroundColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent))
```

But, I can't find the code that changes its surface color!!

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

chip.chipBackgroundColor = getColorStateList(your color)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But It is not working.
That way, only background color changes. When I want to change background transparent, surface color (default white) remains. So entire chip's background remains white.

Comment: did you found any workaround ?